# SvelteKit and SASS Undefined Mixin VS Code Issue

Tags: sass, sveltekit, scss-mixins

I have the following error in VS Code in my SvelteKit project:

```
Error in referenced file

Error: Undefined mixin.
   ╷
10 │         @include h1;
   │         ^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  app\src\routes\+page.svelte.vite-preprocess.scss 10:3  root stylesheetsvelte(style)
```

My style looks like:

```
<style lang="scss">
    #title {
        @include h1;
    }

</style>
```

In my vite.config.ts file it's setup with the preProcessorOptions:

```
import { sveltekit } from "@sveltejs/kit/vite";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                additionalData: '@use "src/lib/styles/mixins.scss" as *;',
            },
        },
    },
});
```

The mixin actually worked and it updates, however VS code still gives me this error. Is there anyway I can remove the error even though everything is working on paper?